# A combinatorics and divisibility puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, puzzle

I've recently encountered the following puzzle that seems a bit too "mathy" for Puzzling Stack Exchange so I decided to ask here. This is not a homework.

The numbers from $1$ to $15$ must be put in a sequence with the two numbers fixed:

- The $4$th number is $15$.
- The $8$th number is $8$.

($1$-based counting)

How many such sequences exist where the sum of any $3$ neighboring numbers is divisible by $3$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Since 15 is already divisible by 3 the two numbers on the left must sum to 3, same for the numbers on the right. For 8 the same condition is that the two sums must give 1 as a reminder. But I don't see how to move to counting from here.

Comment: Hint: Just consider the values mod 3. What can you say about such a sequence of 5 0's, 5 1's, 5 2's? And furthermore what if the 4th is 0, and the 8th is 2?

Comment: Thanks, Calvin. Nice idea. I didn't make this step from pairwise sums to just reminders. I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: Going to the left from 15 (0) we see that the second and third reminders can be one of 0 + 0, 1 + 2, 2 + 1. Thus, the first one must be 0. I guess I need to fill the gaps in the same way between 15(0) and 8(2) and up to the end and then count the ways to put 5 0's, 5 1's, and 5 2's. This is about what I was going to try but simpler. I wonder if this long chain of sums is the only way to solve it.

Comment: Going to the right i.e. between 15(0) and 8(2) we have only one option: 0 2 1 0 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_i$ be the $i$-th number of the sequence then $a_i\equiv a_{i+3}\equiv -a_{i+1}-a_{i+2}\mod 3$ since the sum of three consecutive numbers is $0$ modulo $3$.

By the given restrictions we get $$a_i\equiv\begin{cases}0&\text{if }3\mid (i-1)\\1&\text{if }3\mid i\\2&\text{if }3\mid(i-2)\end{cases} \mod 3.$$

Every way of putting numbers that satisfy the above, is a solution. So the total number of possibilities is $4!\cdot 5!\cdot 4!$ (number of permutations for elements with index $\equiv1\mod 3$ and $i\neq 4$ times number of permutations for elements with index $\equiv0\mod3$ times number of permutations for elements with index $\equiv2\mod3$ and $i\neq8$).

Comment: Nice. Thanks :)